# Как правильно перегрузить метод

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование, полиморфизм

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;

class Function
{
public:
    double result(double f)
    {
        return 666;
    }
};

void plot(Function f, double a, double b, int steps, char* nameFile)
{
    ofstream file(nameFile);
    for(int i = 0; i < steps + 1; i++)
    {
        double x = ((b - a) / steps) * i + a;
        file << x << " " << f.result(x) << endl;
    }
    file.close();
}


double rr(double (*f)(double), double* array, int n)
{
    double s = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        double m = 1;
        for(int l = 0; l < n; l++)
        {
            if(l == j) continue;
            m *= 1/(array[j] - array[l]);
        }
        s += f(array[j])*m;
    }
    return s;
}

class F: public Function
{
public:
    double result(double x)
    {
        return sin(x);
    }
};

class Newton: public Function
{
private:
    double* array;
    int n;
    double (*f)(double);
public:
    Newton(double (*f)(double), double* array, int n)
    {
        this->f = f;
        this->array = array;
        this->n = n;
    }

    double result(double x)
    {
        double s = f(array[0]);

        for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            double r = rr(f, array, i);
            for(int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++)
            {
                r *= x - array[j];
            }
            s += r;
        }
        return s;
    }
};

int main() {
    int n = 10; 
    double a = -3.1415*3; 
    double b = 3.1415*3;  
    double array[10];     
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        array[i] = ((b - a)/n)*i + a;
    }

    Newton p(&sin, array, n);
    F f;
    plot(f, -3.1415*3, 3.1415*3, 100, "f.txt");
    plot(p, -3.1415*3, 3.1415*3, 100, "pnf.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

В файле pnf.txt почему-то высвечиваются значения 666, хотя я переопределил метод result в дочернем классе Newton. А вот почему-то с f.txt все нормально и там нет значений 666. Подскажите почему?

Comment: Вообще-то у меня оба файла совпадают до байта... И это логично: в `plot` вы передаете `Function`, у которого нет виртуальных функций, да еще и по значению...

Comment: *"я переопределил метод result в дочернем классе Newton"* - ничего подобного. Укажите при переопределении метод как `override`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то поскольку `plot` описана как

```
void plot(Function f, double a, double b, int steps, char* nameFile)
```

то что бы вы ни передавали в нее, какого бы потомка не передали — произойдет срезка, и будет там строго `Function` с его `666`.

Но даже если вы передадите

```
void plot(Function& f, double a, double b, int steps, char* nameFile)
```

ничего не изменится, потому что `result()` не виртуальная функция, а значит, никакого разрешения времени выполнения нет...

Добавьте

```
class Function
{
public:
    virtual double result(double f)
```

и тогда можно будет о чем-то говорить.

А пока — оба файла совершенно одинаковы, оба с `666`.